# Javascript Parsing Table Content to Json

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, html-table

I have table structure like this:

```
<figure class="table">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>[11]</td>
        <td>[12]</td>
        <td>[13]</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</figure>
```

and I need to parse the table content [11], [12], [13] to json below:

```
{
  “block_id”: 11
},
{
  “block_id”: 12
},
{
  “block_id”: 13
}
```

Is there a way using javascript to parse the table contents to json?

Please help.. Thank you

Comment: Get the table element, traverse the tbodies, trs, tds, and strip the square brackets and pair that value with block_id key of an object and add that object to an **array** - you cannot do that with an object...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Just assign an ID to the table body and pass that element to the function!

Table:

```
<table>
  <tbody id="table_body">
    <tr>
      <td>[11]</td>
      <td>[12]</td>
      <td>[13]</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>[14]</td>
      <td>[15]</td>
      <td>[16]</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
function tableToJson(table) {

  var tableObject = [];
  

  for(i = 0 ; i < table.length ; i ++)
  {
    var row = [];
    for(j = 0 ; j < table[i].children.length; j++)
    {
      row.push(table[i].children[j].innerHTML);
    }
    tableObject.push(row);
  }
  
  
    return tableObject;
}

console.log(
   JSON.stringify(
      tableToJson(document.getElementById("table_body").children)
   )
);
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: It’s it ideal to use innerHTML at all. Refer here for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: From MDN: Warning: If your project is one that will undergo any form of security review, using innerHTML most likely will result in your code being rejected. For example, if you use innerHTML in a browser extension and submit the extension to addons.mozilla.org, it will not pass the automated review process.

Answer (score 0):

you can add jQuery, than assign id to  and itrate the values using foreach loop.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tbody>
  <tr id="myTr">
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
<script>
    $(function(){
       var myArr = [{"block_id": 11},{"block_id": 12},{"block_id": 13}];
    $('#myTr').html('');
    $.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
      $('#myTr').append('<td>'+value.block_id+'</td>');
    });

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: This solution will be helpful as The OP did not asked for jQuery. The question has tags fo JS. Please refer to the question. The OP Has specifically said JavaScript. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Wrong way around; the OP has a table, and wants the array of objects as JSON.